# Flutter: How to use FutureBuilder like StreamBuilder

Tags: rest, flutter, chat

I am a chat app that uses data from the RestFul server.

This data is received in the form of Future and chatting is not guaranteed real-time.

Because I want to use like a real-time chat. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- upgrade your server in order to use a real Stream in your app (for example a socket)
- build a Dart Stream which calls your server periodically and use it in a StreamBuilder

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQBpOIHE4eE) for more details.